# Numeric input min length 4, max 5 and not 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I make a numeric input with min length 4, max 5 and not 0;

like you can input 1234 but 5th digit shouldn't be 0; So no 12340 also no more than 4999?

---

Answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/665261/billy-moon :
replace(/[^0-9]/,'') -> makes numeric;
replace(/^([0-9]{4})[^1-9]+/,'$1') -> makes 5th digit not 0
replace(/^[^0-4]/,'') ->makes first digit 0-4

Code:

```
$('input').bind('keyup change',function(){
    $(this).attr({ value: $(this).attr('value').replace(/[^0-9]/,'').replace(/^([0-9]{4})[^1-9]+/,'$1').replace(/^[^0-4]/,'') })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add an keyup event that validates the field, and replaces bad input something like this

```
$('input').bind('keyup change',function(){
$(this).attr({ value: $(this).attr('value').replace(/[^0-9]/,'').replace(/^([0-9]{4})[^1-9]+/,'$1') })
})
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, does it need any plugin or need old jquery, I am on v1.4.2. and replace is not a function error shows.

Comment: Ok parially is doing the job, accpting only numbers, and 5th number cannot be 0 but is not limitin, min 4 max 5 or at least max 5

Comment: I've added max length to input and not seems ok.

Comment: replace is a plain old javascript function that operates on a string. Why don't you post your final code so people searching in the future can see the finished result.

Comment: Just one more thing, How to limit first digit to 0-4 so no more than 49999?

Comment: add an extra `.replace(/^[^0-4]/,'')`

Comment: what is this for - I am trying to imagine a scenario but coming up short

Comment: :). Polls, there are 4865 polls so I'm just trying to make some validation that Operators will not screw, or they will screw less. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can't set a "min-length", but you can validate the input whenever you want (on change, form submit, etc):

```
if(!input.value.test(/^\d{4}[1-9]?$/)){
   // fail
}
```